# MY SQL - time diff between a date and the next day at 6 PM

Tags: mysql

I need to compare 2 dates. In case the difference between the first and the second date is > than the diff between the first date and the next day at 6 PM, then its not on time. Else its on time.

Been doing something like this, but didnt figure out how to include de specific time for the next day:

`WHEN DATEDIFF(approved_at, created_at) > DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL 1 DAY), created_at) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;`

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: DATEDIFF ignores time part of the datetime value. 6 PM, 5AM or something else - this does not effect the output.

Answer (score 1):

try using this

```sql
STR_TO_DATE(
    CONCAT(DATE(DATE_ADD(
        CASE
            WHEN WEEKDAY(created_at) = 4 THEN DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL 2 DAY)
            ELSE created_at
        END,
        INTERVAL 1 DAY
    )), ' 18:00:00'),
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'
)
```

It is not the most beautiful solution but i think it will work just fine, i also think you will need to be careful if the date it's on the weekend

Answer (score 0):

Completely misread context of post.  The final answer you are looking for ultimately is if the approve date is AFTER (or not) 6pm on the following day.

First, get the date portion of when the entry was created by stripping the time

```
select date( created_at )
```

So, if it was 2021-08-24 at 7:05pm, it would truncate down to just 2021-08-24.

Now, add 1 full day to it.

```
select date_add( date( created_at ), interval 1 day )
```

and you have now advanced to the next day which would be 2021-08-25.

Now, add 18hours which is 6pm

```
select addtime( date_add( date( created_at ), interval 1 day ), '18:00:00' )
```

Now, from the CREATED_AT original date/time, you would now have example from 2021-08-24 at 7:05pm now becomes a must be approved by date/time of 2021-08-25 at 6pm.  Now, just see if the approved is GREATER than this definitive time

Just to see the pieces as they go, just get each component to see how they work

```
select 
      YT.created_at,
      date( YT.created_at )  JustTheDate,
      date_add( date( YT.created_at ), interval 1 day ) BeginOfNextDay,
      addtime( date_add( date( YT.created_at ), interval 1 day ), '18:00:00' ) At6PmNextDay,
      YT.approved_at,

      case when addtime( date_add( date( YT.created_at ), interval 1 day ), '18:00:00' ) < YT.approved_at 
            then 'ON-TIME' 
            else 'LATE' end as WasItOnTime
   from
      YourTable YT
```

addtime( date_add( date( created_at ), interval 1 day ), '18:00:00' )